# Downloading CSV file from API which can have a variable number of columns

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to download stock market information from an API link. Depending on the stock name being requested, the downloaded CSV file can have a variable number of columns. I have used the following code to download the CSV file into a specific sheet on Excel named "TIS". The stock name being requested can be changed in the Sheet named "Inputs" cell 2,1 to whichever company you may be interested in (for example, AAPL for Apple). The code works when there are exactly 41 columns of information for the requested stock but when there are less than 41 columns, you get an error. If there are more than 41 columns, the extra columns are not downloaded. Is there a way to download all the columns in the requested CSV file regardless of the number of columns there maybe?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Dim stockname As String
    stockname= Sheets("Inputs").Cells(2, 1)

    Dim pq As Object
    For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    pq.Delete
    Next

    Sheets("TIS").Select
    Cells.Clear


ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="" & stockname & "TIS", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(""https://stockrow.com/api/companies/" & stockname & "/financials.xlsx?dimension=T&section=Income%20Statement&sort=desc""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    " & stockname & "_Sheet = Source{[Item=""" & stockname & """,Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(" & stockname & "_Sheet,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type " & _
    "any}, {""Column4"", type any}, {""Column5"", type any}, {""Column6"", type any}, {""Column7"", type any}, {""Column8"", type any}, {""Column9"", type any}, {""Column10"", type any}, {""Column11"", type any}, {""Column12"", type any}, {""Column13"", type any}, {""Column14"", type any}, {""Column15"", type any}, {""Column16"", type any}, {""Column17"", type any}, {""C" & _
    "olumn18"", type any}, {""Column19"", type any}, {""Column20"", type any}, {""Column21"", type any}, {""Column22"", type any}, {""Column23"", type any}, {""Column24"", type any}, {""Column25"", type any}, {""Column26"", type any}, {""Column27"", type any}, {""Column28"", type any}, {""Column29"", type any}, {""Column30"", type any}, {""Column31"", type any}, {""Colum" & _
    "n32"", type any}, {""Column33"", type any}, {""Column34"", type any}, {""Column35"", type any}, {""Column36"", type any}, {""Column37"", type any}, {""Column38"", type any}, {""Column39"", type any}, {""Column40"", type any}, {""Column41"", type any}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & stockname & "TIS;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & stockname & "TIS]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "" & stockname & "TIS"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
End With
```

Comment: You should be able to handle that in Power Query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .. Edit the query addition removing the columns array like below

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="" & stockname & "TIS", Formula:= _
"let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(""https://stockrow.com/api/companies/" & stockname & "/financials.xlsx?dimension=T&section=Income%20Statement&sort=desc""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    " & stockname & "_Sheet = Source{[Item=""" & stockname & """,Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(" & stockname & "_Sheet,{})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

Tried this with stockname with less columns such as FB, BABA. It's working. No error issues. The column array makes it necessary to have all those 41 columns in the source. Hence, there appears following error message (BABA).

[image]

Once you remove the columns array, whatever columns are there in the source will be queried. BABA has only 26 Columns data as below.

[image]

I think the data starts from 30th JUNE 2010. Tried that with Microsoft(MSFT) which should have data before that. But no luck. So you will have Columns till "AO" (41) not more than that now. As you keep this running through next quarter one column will be added to make it 42